# How can Python decompress data from Java compress with zip

Tags: python, java

I wrote a demo with Java and Python to show my problem. My situation is Java to compress and Python to decompress. The Java code is

```java
String base64Str;
byte[] inBytes = "{\"a\":\"b\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
){
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("0"));
    zipOutputStream.write(inBytes);
    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    base64Str = Base64Encoder.encode(out.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(base64Str);
}catch (Exception e){
    return;
}

byte[] bytes = Base64Decoder.decode(base64Str);
try(
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);){
    zin.getNextEntry();
    byte[] buffer =  new byte[1024];
    int offset = -1;
    while ((offset = zin.read(buffer))!=-1){
        out.write(buffer,0,offset);
    }
    System.out.println(new String(buffer,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the python code is

```py
s = 'UEsDBBQACAgIAOl9VlYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAMKtWSlSyUkpSqgUAUEsHCJxc9msLAAAACQAAAA=='
bytes = base64.b64decode(s)
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(bytes))
```

The variable `s` in the Python code is Java's `System.out.println(new String(buffer,StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` output, and Python gives me a wrong information

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[101], line 3
      1 s = 'UEsDBBQACAgIAOl9VlYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAMKtWSlSyUkpSqgUAUEsHCJxc9msLAAAACQAAAA=='
      2 bytes = base64.b64decode(s)
----> 3 zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(bytes))

File d:\python38\lib\zipfile.py:1269, in ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1267 try:
   1268     if mode == 'r':
-> 1269         self._RealGetContents()
   1270     elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1271         # set the modified flag so central directory gets written
   1272         # even if no files are added to the archive
   1273         self._didModify = True

File d:\python38\lib\zipfile.py:1336, in ZipFile._RealGetContents(self)
   1334     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1335 if not endrec:
-> 1336     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1337 if self.debug > 1:
   1338     print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues with your code.

**First:** you don't close the `ZipOutputStream` before taking its result via the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. That means that `ZipOutputStream` can't write the necessary end-of-file content. To fix this use nested try-with-resource like this:

```
String base64Str;
byte[] inBytes = "{\"a\":\"b\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
  try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out)) {
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("0"));
    zipOutputStream.write(inBytes);
    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
  }
  base64Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(out.toByteArray());
  System.out.println(base64Str);
} catch (Exception e) {
  return;
}
```

Note that Java can apparently tolerate the lack of the end-of-file header (especially when used like you did), while Python considers it a fatal error.

Generally speaking, if your goal is to just compress a single stream of data, then ZIP isn't quite the right format for that: it's meant as an archive containing files (with file names, metadata, an index, ...).

Other formats such as GZIP are simpler and also widely supported. Java has [`GZIPInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) and [`GZIPOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) for that.

**Second:** you use `buffer` for your output at the end, when you should be using `out.toByteArray()`:

```
System.out.println(new String(out.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This will guarantee that the whole file content will be printed and it won't contain spurious nul-bytes.